How can I simultaneously have JWT token-based and cookie-based authentication in a Blazor Server project using .NET 8?
I have a Blazor Server app project authenticated via ASP.NET Identity cookies, and I've added several APIs to it using the minimal API approach. These APIs are intended to be called through a mobile application, and it's necessary for the APIs to be authenticated via JWT tokens. What should I do to achieve this?
Current authentication Config:
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider,     IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
}).AddIdentityCookies();


builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
.AddRoles<Role>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<Infrastructure.Persistence.ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddSignInManager()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();


I would like to thank the creator of the this video, as I have utilized it in my application. In summary, I will outline the tasks that need to be performed:
As the Blazor application uses cookies for authentication, we need to specify and configure the default authentication scheme for cookies and identify it with a name in the following way:
services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application") // specify application default Authentication Schema with 'Identity.Application' name
.AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>  // add cookies with Schema name 'Identity.Application'
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
});

Then, we need to specify the JWT token authentication with its settings and introduce it to the system with a name as follows:
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => // add JwtBearer and specify name as 'Bearer'
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = " you site link blah blah",
        ValidIssuer = "You Site link Blah  blah",
        IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ssddsd")),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

API Controller Or Minimal API needs to specify the authentication schema JWT token-based authentication with Authorize attributes :
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] // specify AuthenticationSchemes here
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/<TestController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}

In minimal Api :
app.MapGet("api/test", [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] ()=>"Hello");

With these settings, we have implemented two authentication methods in the application.Blazor components will use cookies for authentication, and API's Using JWT Tokens
Compelete Config Code
services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application") // specify application default Authentication Schema with 'Identity.Application' name
.AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>  // add cookies with Schema name 'Identity.Application'
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => // add JwtBearer and specify name as 'Bearer'
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = " you site link blah blah",
        ValidIssuer = "You Site link Blah  blah",
        IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ssddsd")),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

